# python-daemon start multiple instances of same program and passing in instance specific arguments

Tags: python, python-daemon

I have a log mining tool I have written. I can launch it using nohup and pass in arguments like what file it is to parse (it uses a platform independent tail class I wrote in Python). However I would like it to start as an init script or from the command line (as a daemon). And I would like to be able to start multiple instances if there is more than one log file to look at on the same server.

I have looked at the [python-daemon package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) but it is unclear in the reference documents if it is possible to pass in *process/instance specific arguments*. e.g. like what log file each daemon instance of the program is supposed to scan.

One of the issues I am trying to get my head around is how to stop or restart the individual daemon instances created.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do the exact same thing today, multiple (same) apps that need to run as Daemons.
I did not use the new python-daemon package because I've never used it, but I've used the Daemon from Sander Marechal ([A simple unix/linux daemon in Python](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/)) many time before.

I've created a simple test app, not the greatest python code, but it works as expected. The sample uses a single extra parameter that can be used like this: `./runsample.py start <param>`

You will see a new log file, and pid file created in /tmp for each running Daemon.

You can get the Daemon class from here: [A simple unix/linux daemon in Python](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/)

**The Test App**

```
import sys, time
from daemon import Daemon

#simple test app that writes to a file every second
#this is just to check that the correct daemons are running

class testapp(Daemon):

    ID = 0

    def __init__(self, id):
        print 'Init (ID): ' + id
        #set the params
        self.ID = id
        #set the pid file
        pid = '/tmp/testapp-' + str(id) + '.pid'
        #init the base with the pid file location
        Daemon.__init__(self, pid)


    #this is the overwritten method from the article by Sander Marechal
    # http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #open file, append mode
            f = open('/tmp/log-' + self.ID + '.log', 'a')
            #write
            f.write(str(time.time()))
            #close
            f.close()
            #wait
            time.sleep(1)
```

**The Init Script / Daemon**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#
# Multiple daemons for the same app test
#

import sys
from testapp import testapp

#check is anough arguments are passed
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "usage: %s start|stop|restart <param>" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(2)

#get the extra arguments
id = sys.argv[2]
print 'Param (ID): ' + sys.argv[2]
#start the app with the parameters
daemon = testapp(id)


#from the article by Sander Marechal
# http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
        print 'Start'
        daemon.start()
    elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
        daemon.stop()
        print 'Stop'
    elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
        print 'Restarting...'
        daemon.restart()
        print 'Restarted'
    else:
        print "Unknown command"
        sys.exit(2)
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
sys.exit(2)
```

I hope this works for you as well.

Comment: Thanks... I'm on to something else now (got it running but for only one file ... which is not ideal but works for now), but want to return to this. When I get the chance I'll try this out.